# Adding a property to Add() method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add a property to a `Add()` method but it doesn't seem to work. I'm sure I'm missing something.

```
  Items.Add(new ItemProperties
                    {
                        Item = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i]),
                        Description = lines[i + 1],
                        Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i + 2]),
                        UnitPrice = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i + 3]),
                        Tax = Convert.ToInt32(lines[i + 4]),
                        TotalTax = 34234,
                        Total //<-- Error: Invalid initializer member declarator 

                    });
```

`ItemProperties` class:

```
  public class ItemProperties
        {
            public int Item { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
            public int UnitPrice { get; set; }
            public int Tax { get; set; }
            public int TotalTax { get; set; }
            public int Total {
                get
                {
                    return Quantity * UnitPrice;
                } 
                set
                {
                }
            } 
        }
```

I'm getting two errors:

> Invalid initializer member declarator
>
> The name 'Total' does not exist in the current context

What I want the `Total` property to do is to add the result of `Quantity * UnitPrice` to the `Add()` method

Comment: Just delete the line, it doesn't make sense.  Get rid of the empty setter as well.

Comment: You don't want to _"add the result of Quantity * UnitPrice to the Add() method"_. You want that `Total` returns `Quantity * UnitPrice` automatically which it already does.

Comment: It is still curious that the error message is so bad and really misses the point, though this would be an easy one to detect by the compiler.

Comment: @Georg: Why? The compiler is right. It is invalid to declare an initializer member like `Total` without assigning a value. And it is correct that `Total` is not an available method or property since `Total` is used without an instance of `ItemProperties`. The compiler does not know that you mean the property of `ItemProperties`. How could he be expected to know that?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, this part is correct but "name does not exist" misses the point that no value is provided. Providing just anything would fix the code. Indeed Total does exist in the current context, so the compiler tells something that is not true.

Comment: @Georg: Ok, the second error is redundant with the first. But i guess it is thrown anyway and it would be too expensive to rewrite the compiler to omit it in such cases. _" Indeed Total does exist"_ No, because used in this way it is not a (valid) initializer member but a variable which "does not exist in the current context". If you declare a (local) variable `Total` this error disappears but the initializer member declarator is still invalid.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry I forgot about list initializers. Taking them into account, the error message totally makes sense, though it is still confusing, apparently

Comment: Note that Object and Collection Initializers have a similar syntax and that the compiler does not know if you initialize an object or collection in the first place. You can initialize a collection as follows: `var c = new List<int>{Total}`, presuming `Total` is an `int` variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int Total 
{
    get
    {
        return Quantity * UnitPrice;
    } 
    set
    {
    }
}
```

change to

```
public int Total 
{
    get
    {
        return Quantity * UnitPrice;
    } 
}
```

you can use property with only getter

Comment: And remove the total-field when adding the property.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have setter implemented for Total, but try to set some value for it. So I propose to either implement setter or remove usage of Total in initialization logic

```
public int Total {
                get
                {
                    return Quantity * UnitPrice;
                } 
                set
                {
                   // you need to add some code
                }
```